# How to split a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if there is a way to split the cells in imagelist into 8 characters segments putting each 8 characters on sheet2 and include field1, field2, field3 for each line?

```
IDNUM   FIELD1  FIELD2  FIELD3  CONVSTATUS  DUPEID  IMAGELIST
7   Person1 07/20/1982  20321   4   0   000001370000013900000140000001410000014200000143000001440000014500000146000001470000014800000149000001500000015100000152000001530000015400000155000001560000015700000158000001590000016000000161000001620000016300000164000001650000016600000167000001680000016
8   Person2 08/20/1984  240761  4   1   000002030000020400000205000002060000020700000208000002090000021000000212000002160000021700000218000002190000022000000221000002220000022300000224000002250000022600000227000002280000022900000230000002310000023200000233000002340000023500000236000002370000023
9   Person3 09/13/1986  240762  4   1   00000403000004040000040500000406000004070000040800000409000004100000041200000416
​
```

This is what I am hoping to archive in the end. (shortened due to imagelist can very greatly in size)

```
Person1 07/20/1982  20321   00000137
Person1 07/20/1983  20322   00000139
Person1 07/20/1984  20323   00000140
Person2 08/20/1984  240761  00000203
Person2 08/20/1984  240761  00000204
Person2 08/20/1984  240761  00000205
Person3 09/13/1986  240762  00000403
Person3 09/13/1986  240762  00000404
Person3 09/13/1986  240762  00000405
```

Comment: `Data|Text To Columns|Fixed Width` on Column IMAGELIST?

Comment: Can we assume that the length of IMAGELIST will always be divisible by 8?

Comment: yes always a 8 characters

Comment: Welcome to SO! Reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you get an answer sooner. Remember, this isn't a code-writing service, so post what you've got & we can help you fix it. If you don't know where to start, try using the Macro Recorder.

Comment: Siddharth Rout -  
Data|Text To Columns|Fixed Width  does split it but would it not be a lot harder to achieve the end results from multiple columns rather then from the original one cell?

Comment: I can fully respect that. Its just that my attempts at this are so far off that i am not sure what there is to build on.

Comment: A simple loop and `Mid` will get the characters out.  You can then drop them into a column and pull the other text over.  I suspect an outer loop for each original item can drive this and get the other info.  Here is the inner loop.  `ActiveCell` would be whatever range is used for each cell in `IMAGELIST`.  `For i = 1 To Len(ActiveCell) Step 8 : img_item = Mid(ActiveCell, i, 8) : Next`

Comment: And are the columns shown in your second example the only ones that you need copied into Sheet2?

Comment: If your data comes from access like the [possible duplicate](http://superuser.com/q/921311/348859) posted over on SuperUser, then there's an easy [solution in Access](http://superuser.com/a/921325/348859).

Answer (score 1):

With **IDNUM** in A1 (as per the sample image), run through this code.

[image: IMAGESET split]

```
Sub split_img_set()
    Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, v As Long, vi As Long, vVALs As Variant

    With ActiveSheet   '<-set this worksheet reference properly!!
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(lr + 3, 2).Resize(1, 4) = Array(.Cells(1, 2).Value, .Cells(1, 3).Value, .Cells(1, 3).Value, "IMAGES")
        For rw = 2 To lr
            vVALs = .Cells(rw, 2).Resize(1, 6).Value
            vi = Len(vVALs(1, UBound(vVALs, 2)))
            For v = 1 To vi Step 8
                .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3) = Array(vVALs(1, 1), vVALs(1, 2), vVALs(1, 3))
                .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).NumberFormat = "@"
                .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3) = Mid(vVALs(1, UBound(vVALs, 2)), v, 8)
            Next v
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

The results will be created under the existing values. There may have been a posting error but the first two sample IMAGELIST values were *not* directly divisible by *8*, being *255* characters in length.

Comment: Thank you both and SO! Wish I would have ask for some guidance earlier. Embarrassing but I have been working on this for more then a few weeks. But now I can study what you guys achieved in no time and find out where I was going wrong. Thanks again you rock!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet for you to get started with (assuming you're copying from Sheet1 to Sheet2):

```
Sub Test2()
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Set wsSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim LastRow As Integer, RowsToCopy As Integer, Counter As Integer, Step As Integer, ILCol As Integer
ILCol = 4
Counter = 2
LastRow = wsSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, After:=[A1]).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    RowsToCopy = Len(wsSheet.Cells(i, ILCol)) / 8
    Step = 1
    For t = 1 To RowsToCopy
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Counter, 4).Value = CStr(Mid(wsSheet.Cells(i, ILCol).Value, Step, 8))
        Step = Step + 8
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Next t
Next i

End Sub
```

Just change the ILCol = 4 to whatever column the IMAGELIST column is in.  You'll still have to write in a loop to copy over the other columns, then format the new column as "00000000", but this should be a good start.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. Bummer still at work. I will have to wait till later tonight to work on getting the loop to get the other fields.Thank you so much for starting me down the right path. I was lost.

Comment: Happy to help.  Let me know if you run into any roadblocks getting the other columns in.  Should be a pretty simple For loop.